# How to fix Path Manipulation error given by fortify?

Tags: email-attachments, fortify

```
I have path Manipulation problem in addAttachment.

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
hssWorkBook.write(baos);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "application/excel");
helper.addAttachment("XYZ information - "+XYZ+".xls", ds);
helper.setText(text.toString(), true);
```

Iam trying to add an xls as attachment from the already created workbook but  Fortify is giving path manipulation error in addAttachment.
How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Where does the variable `XYZ` come from in your example?

Fortify believes this variable is constructed full or partically from untrusted/unvalidated data.

Are you doing some form of validation on it?  Is it coming from an untrusted source (all non-hardcoded values are considered untrusted in strictly security sense).

Take a look at [OWASP's Path Traversal page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).